# How do I take shell input literally? (i.e. keeping quotes etc. intact)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I am trying to write a bash script so that I will use to replace my egrep command. I want to be able to take the exact same input that is given to my script and feed it to egrep. 
i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
PARAMS=$@
`egrep "$PARAMS"`
```

But I have noticed that if I echo what I am executing, that the quotes have been removed as follows:

> ./customEgrep -nr "grep my ish" *

returns

> egrep -nr grep my ish (file list from the expanded *)

Is there a way that I can take the input literally so I can use it directly with egrep?

Comment: Note that there is no need to put the `egrep` command in backquotes in your script. You aren't trying to capture its output; you just want to let it go to standard output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this:

```
egrep "$@"
```

The quotes you type are not passed to the script; they're used to determine word boundaries.  Using `"$@"` preserves those word boundaries, so `egrep` will get the same arguments as it would if you ran it directly.  But you still won't see quotation marks if you `echo` the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

`"` is a special char. you need to use escape character in order to retrieve `"`

use

```
./customEgrep -nr "\"grep my ish\"" *
```

If you don't need to do any parameter expansion in the argument, you can use
single quotes to avoid the need to escape the double quotes:

```
./customerEgrep -nr '"grep my ish"' *
```

Answer (score 2):

`$@` is special when quoted.  Try:

```
value=$( egrep "$@" )
```

It's not clear to me why you are using bacticks and ignoring the result, so I've used the `$()` syntax and assigned the value.

If for some reason you want to save the parameters to use later, you can also do things like:

```
for i; do args="$args '$i'"; done  # Save the arguments
eval grep $args # Pass the arguments to grep without resetting $1,$2,...
eval set $args  # Restore the arguments
grep "$@"       # Use the restored arguments
```